# Error Message in Strongly Typed View - What is the "dictionary"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

Here is a sample of an error message when the wrong type is passed into a strongly typed view:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'foo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'bar'.
```

This error says **"this dictionary"** requires a different model. My question is, why "dictionary"? It would make more sense to me if the error message said *"this class requires a model item of type 'bar'"*.

What dictionary is the error message alluding to?

Comment: The model is serialized as a dictionary of form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` is a Framework class.  Dictionaries are used to hold Key/Value collections in MVC.  The error message says that the `Dictionary` was initialized with a different type than the items that MVC is attempting to place into it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

[This Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=model+dictionary+mvc+msdn) shows a number of dictionaries that ASP.NET MVC uses.

Comment: Thanks Robert- but what dictionary? I guess I'm asking what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't know which one; you haven't shown us your code.  If I were to guess, I'd say it's the `ViewDataDictionary` or the `ModelDataDictionary`.

Comment: Hmmm - it would seem reasonable that the view get's compiled as a class, and that class expects a model of a certain type. I guess behind the scenes there is a Dictionary which is used to instantiate the view class (just a guess).

Comment: The source code for ASP.NET MVC is [freely available](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781), if you really want to know the nitty gritty.  Do a search in the source code for *"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type"*.